# Xcode 4 -- want my menu of alphabetized methods back

Tags: xcode, xcode4

In Xcode 3 I used the menu at the top of my editing window to navigate between methods (and other things), which was useful because it was alphabetized. In XCode 4 (the jump bar, I think it's called) is no longer alphabetized.

I didn't see a preference to make it so... is there one?

I suppose the thinking is that you don't need it, since there is a class navigator at the left (left for me, anyway) that shows the methods alphabetized.

Except that only classes in my Classes group show up here. I have lots of classes in a dozen or so other groups, and I don't want to just toss everything into one group.

Any way to get classes in my other groups to show up?

I did notice that when I show ALL classes, they do show up under NSObject, but that navigator is much too cluttered to be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, from the Jump Bar help page:

"Tip: Hold down the Command key when selecting a level in the path menu to view its items alphabetically."